# openldap forgot rootdn password but having root access on DC

Tags: openldap

Hi I had setup a small office network before with openldap but I forgot my rootdn password and wondering if it is possible to add a new user / change the rootdn password using local linux root account.

One method I am thinking about is to stop the slapd service and use slapcat to dump the whole AD into ldif file, add a new entry and restore it from the file. However that require stopping the service, is there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The thing I did at the end is change the {SSHA} password in the slapd.conf file.

run `server slapd restart`